# GUI randomly stopped working

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, undefined, uicontrol

My GUI was running perfectly well before I tried to change one little thing (it was only to print something to the screen, it shouldn't have made a difference). Suddenly I started getting this message

> Undefined function 'Stacks' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
>
> Error in
>   @(hObject,eventdata)Stacks('Stack1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Now even when I use my Time Machine to try to get back to old version of the GUI that I know for a fact worked they will not either.

Has anyone had anything similar happen or does anyone have any advice? I already tried restarting MATLAB.

Comment: _I tried to change one little thing_: you should post the relevant code and post the whole error message.

Comment: Your GUI can't find the function `Stacks`. Is this a file named `Stacks.m` or a function within the same file?